# Active directory integration with Corda

Tags: corda

Hyperledger Fabric allows to integrate LDAP with Fabric CA. This will help an organization to reuse their existing user access management to Fabric application. Do we have any such functionality available for r3 corda where we can integrate existing LDAP to Corda authentication layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seems ambiguous but here it goes.

If you are asking about **RPC connection credentials**, then I'd probably follow Adel's suggestion of using a database as the intermediary, in short:

node.conf `dataSource` --[points to](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/clientrpc.html#rpc-security-management)--> RDBMS --syncs with--> LDAP

You'd have to setup a RDBMS/LDAP sync mechanism; if JPA is relevant to you as an ORM, you can probably use the entities [predefined here](https://manosbatsis.github.io/corbeans/docs/data-rpc.html) by yours truly.

If about **app-level user auth**, have a look at [Corda Accounts](https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/master/docs.md). You should be able to map between account IDs and (R)DNs using a UUID originating in either side.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that in an indirect way:

- Typically your `node.conf` would define the RPC users and their privileges as a static list:

  ```
  rpcUsers=[
      {
          username=exampleUser
          password=examplePass
          permissions=[
              "ALL"
          ]
      },
      ...
  ]
  ```
- But Corda has another option, which is using a database as a source for credentials. When using this approach you have to do the following:

  - Your `node.conf` will now provide role names instead of user name.
  - Your database must define several tables: `users`, `user_roles`, and `roles_permissions`.
- This way you can add/remove users or grant/revoke privileges by doing it in the database without the need of modifying your `node.conf` or restarting your node.
- I'm sure with this approach, you can create an integration with your LDAP to update those tables.
- You can find more details on this approach [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/clientrpc.html#authenticationauthorisation-data).